# Divisor problems and fractional part

Tags: calculus

I would like to know if the following assumptions are correct:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}=\sum _{n=1}^x \frac{x}{n}-\sum _{n=1}^x \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor$$
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\simeq -\sum _{n=1}^x \sigma _0(n)+x (\log (x)+\gamma )+\frac{1}{2}$$

which is very similar to the popular formula
$$\sum _{n=1}^x \sigma _0(n)=A(x)+2 \gamma  x-x+x \log (x)+\frac{1}{4}$$
Note than $$\sum _{n=1}^x \frac{x}{n}=x H_x$$ and
$$\text{Normal}\left[\text{Series}\left[x H_x,\{x,\infty ,3\}\right]\right]=\frac{1}{120 x^3}-\frac{1}{12 x}+x (\log (x)+\gamma )+\frac{1}{2}$$and Divisor sum DivisorSigma[0, n]

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\{x/n\}$ doesn't converge, for $n > x, \{x/n\} = x/n$

Comment: i think that $$\text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac{x}{n}-\left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor$$ so $$\sum _{n=1}^x \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^x \frac{x}{n}-\sum _{n=1}^x \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor$$ the question is if $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^x \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$   ??